# Command KILL can send all signals?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, command

I wondered if all the signals could potentially be sent on a process with the Kill command.

I have looked at the manual of Kill and Signal (section 7) but I don't know if the signals present in Linux can all be used with Kill.

thanks

Comment: can you mark the correct answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can.

You can use it like this:

`kill [options] <pid> [...]`

Example:

`kill -USR1 6127`

This will send the USR1 signal to process with pid 6127

Or else with signals numbers:

`kill -9 6127`

All this is detailed on kill manual and you can see it typing `man kill` on your terminal, the output will be something like this:

> NAME
>          kill - send a signal to a process
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          kill [options]  [...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          The default signal for kill is TERM.  Use -l or -L to list available signals.  Particularly useful signals include HUP, INT,
>   KILL, STOP, CONT, and 0.  Alternate signals may be specified in three
>   ways:
>          -9, -SIGKILL or -KILL.  Negative PID values may be used to choose whole process groups; see the PGID column in ps command output.
>   A PID of -1 is special; it indicates all processes  except  the  kill
>          process itself and init.

You can type `kill -l` to see a short list of signals or you can take a look at the signal(7) manual with `man 7 signal` to see a complete list of signals with descriptions:

> Standard signals
>          Linux supports the standard signals listed below.  Several signal numbers are architecture-dependent, as indicated in the "Value"
>   column.  (Where three values are given, the first one is usually valid
>          for  alpha  and sparc, the middle one for x86, arm, and most other architectures, and the last one for mips.  (Values for parisc
>   are not shown; see the Linux kernel source for signal numbering on
>   that
>          architecture.)  A - denotes that a signal is absent on the corresponding architecture.)
>
> ```
>    First the signals described in the original POSIX.1-1990 standard.
>
>    Signal     Value     Action   Comment
>    ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>    SIGHUP        1       Term    Hangup detected on controlling terminal
>                                  or death of controlling process
>    SIGINT        2       Term    Interrupt from keyboard
>    SIGQUIT       3       Core    Quit from keyboard
>    SIGILL        4       Core    Illegal Instruction
>    SIGABRT       6       Core    Abort signal from abort(3)
>    SIGFPE        8       Core    Floating point exception
>    SIGKILL       9       Term    Kill signal
>    SIGSEGV      11       Core    Invalid memory reference
>    SIGPIPE      13       Term    Broken pipe: write to pipe with no
>                                  readers
>    SIGALRM      14       Term    Timer signal from alarm(2)
>    SIGTERM      15       Term    Termination signal
>    SIGUSR1   30,10,16    Term    User-defined signal 1
>    SIGUSR2   31,12,17    Term    User-defined signal 2
>    SIGCHLD   20,17,18    Ign     Child stopped or terminated
>    SIGCONT   19,18,25    Cont    Continue if stopped
>    SIGSTOP   17,19,23    Stop    Stop process
>    SIGTSTP   18,20,24    Stop    Stop typed at terminal
>    SIGTTIN   21,21,26    Stop    Terminal input for background process
>    SIGTTOU   22,22,27    Stop    Terminal output for background process
>
>    The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.
> ```

And a lot of more info about signals. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. There are many ways. Simplest way is:

```
kill -signalnumber  pid1 pid2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

We can send signal to process by  with

kill -signal pid1 [pid2 ... pidn]

kill -9 1379 3001

or you can send signal by name to a set of process

killall -s signal processname

killall -s SIGTERM firefox

However, how the process uses the signal depends of if the this one is in the same user space and if the signal can be catched by the process.

We have a lot of possible signals, manually catched or ignored and other, must by attended.

But others, depends on how you programmed to respond to the signal.

Comment: The ability of a process to catch a signal has nothing to do directly with `kill` being able to send the signal, just with the possible effects that this may cause.

Comment: Completely agree with you. My intention was to elaborate a little more. Reworded the answer waiting for this more consistent. Thank you very much for the advice.